# Login by a temporary link and the re-send verification email mechanism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, user-experience

I register a user without a password and he logins in by a temporary link with I send to his email. Almost the same mechanism as at medium.com. However, I require the initial email verification, that is, the first email a user receive is a verification-and-authentication one, which expires in 24 hours.

Once a user has clicked on a link in the first email, he becomes verified. All subsequent emails allow him log in and expire in 20 minutes.
Now, what if after registration a user doesn't check his email after registration? And then, a day later, he wishes to get a verification link again. How would I go about that?

A user has already been inserted in a database, but not activated. Thus he has to receive and click on a email verification link. Hence, what should the UX be in this case: registration again? Or login in? Or a separate page for "resend verification email"? Or should I just delete users who haven't verificated themselves within a day?

Comment: This question is a little hard to follow.

Comment: If you're using Devise or something like it there's a lot of examples out there on how these things are handled. Plus, look at popular sites like Facebook, Twitter, and even Stack Overflow to see how registration emails are handled by creating a test account or two.